# routerLinkActive does not work with router.navigateByUrl or navigate

Tags: angular

I am changing the route through a `(click)` and not a `[routerLink]` and this is not add class active but change the route

I have to generate an id in the server and after that run `this.router.navigate` and activate the link in my side menu

```
    <li
      routerLinkActive="active" 
      [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: false}">
      <a
        class="nav-link"
        (click)="addNew()"
      >
      </a>
    </li>
```

my function

```
  addNew(): void {
    this.userService.create().subscribe(res => {
      this.router.navigateByUrl(`user/edit/${res.data.id}`);
    });
  }
```

Other places in the menu are using [routerLink] and it works normally

thanks for help

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. I do a lot of processing when a user clicks a link and so I didn't use "routerLink".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`routerLinkActive` relies on having a `routerLink` on either the same host or a descendant in order to know what the candidate links are.

You need to add a `routerLink` to your `<a>`.

```html
<li routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: false}">
  <a routerLink="???" class="nav-link" (click)="addNew()">
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: My mistake mine, I will edit. The problem is not this, but the routerLinkActive

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz to demonstrate the problem

Comment: What didn't you understand?

Comment: I understand the individual components of what you're doing. Your question would benefit from a demo to help break down the problem. And it would help your chances of getting an answer that is specific to your scenario rather than people guessing the rest of your setup, or wondering if you've made any other typos

Comment: Having said that, I think I realise where you're going wrong...

Comment: Answer updated. Without the context of the rest of your page it's hard to see if this is relevant to your situation (hence the need for a demo), but it's not working because you're missing a `routerLink` on the `<a>`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-3nhpkk in stackblitz.

Comment: But I don't want and I can't add a routerlink because I need the id

Comment: Thanks for trying to help

Comment: So it's a "link" that's an "addNew" button. You click it to create an id, and then it shows as active once you get the id? Does it stay as an "addNew" "link", or should it link through to the newly created "thing"?

Comment: i fix adding routerLink and navigate in add new